# Websocket can't connect when deploy on server IIS 7

Tags: websocket, url-rewriting, iis-7, asp.net-core-webapi

```
I have issue when Deploy Websocket on my server on local it working fine,
```

when i deploy on Server, Response from server :
 "failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200", the different between Local and Server it on Server I used UrlRewrite on IIS

Comment: WebSocket is only supported on IIS 8 and above, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that your server doesn't install web socker or your IIS doesn't support web socket.

I suggest you could try to check the windows features to make sure you have installed the websoket protocol.

[image]